# NewRelic monitor Websockets application detalis

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, newrelic, throughput

I have a Jetty server that clients connect to using WebSockets. I am monitoring the performance of the Jetty server using NewRelic. It only counts each new connection to server as one, but it does not provide:

```
1. any throughput information about the number of sent/received messages through the WebSockets. 
2. any insight on how busy the server is
```

Would it be possible to get these information through NewRelic?

Answer (score 2):

Currently New Relic isn't able to detect traffic that's delivered by any protocol other than HTTP, including WebSockets and JMS. If you're willing to do some customization, you can get transactions detected using some annotations and/or custom instrumentation via .XML

The easiest way to sample how this would work is to add the New Relic @Trace annotation to your code and see what's recorded by New Relic https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-java-transaction-traces

I'd get in touch with New Relic support directly for further help with this. support.newrelic.com